# VS 2015 Cannot step through backgroundworker_dowork

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2015, backgroundworker

I'm using C# in VS 2015 targeting the 4.5.2 framework for a normal Windows application (nothing special, actually). I recently moved the project from VS 2013, in case that could be a factor.

Now, when I press F5 I can step (line-by-line) through the Form_Load event. Then a timer ticks and I can step through that code as well. The timer stops itself and calls bgw1.RunWorkerAsync(). I can set a break point inside the bgw1.DoWork routine and it does stop but as soon as it stops, I get a swirling disk and I must wait for several seconds before I regain control over VS. Then, for a moment, every *looks* normal. I press F10 to step one line and then everything stops functioning as one would expect (VS looks like it is running the code but that doesn't seem to be happening).

This is super-easy to reproduce (on my system):

1. Open VS 2015
2. New project...
3. Visual C# / Windows / Classic Desktop
4. Add a timer named "tmr1"; enabled; interval=1000
5. Add a backgroundworker
6. Change the Form1 code to what you see below
7. Set breakpoints on every line that includes "a = "

I can step through Form_Load, Tmr1_Tick, but not bgw1_DoWork.

```
using System;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace BGWTest
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        int a, b, c;
        a = 5; // <-- breakpoint here (can step through this routine)
        b = 7;
        c = a * b;
        this.Text = c.ToString();
        tmr1.Start();
    }

    private void tmr1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        tmr1.Stop();

        int a, b, c;
        a = 15;  // <-- breakpoint here (can step through this routine)
        b = 17;
        c = a * b;
        this.Text = c.ToString();
        bgw1.RunWorkerAsync();
    }

    private void bgw1_DoWork(object sender, DoWorkEventArgs e)
    {
        int a, b, c;
        a = 25;  // <-- breakpoint here (here is where the problem begins)
        b = 27;
        c = a * b;
        UpdateText(c);
    }

    private delegate void UpdateTextCallback(int value);
    private void UpdateText(int value) {
        if (InvokeRequired) {
            UpdateTextCallback deleg = new UpdateTextCallback(UpdateText);
            this.Invoke(deleg, new object[] { value });
        } else {
            this.Text = value.ToString();
        }
    }
}
}
```

I break the code (after trying to take one step inside the bgw_dowork) but it's on the Application.Run() line which launched the form. The form behaves as if it is not running anything (nothing being updated in the UI).

By the way, as long as I don't break in the bgw_dowork routine, everything works fine.

This is something I've not seen before and I've not found anything helpful on SO or anywhere else. I found someone said delete the .suo file and all will be fine. I did this, didn't work.

Then I realized that I had just installed NUnit (through nuget) so I removed it but the problem remains.

Then I deleted all my temp files, did not help. Then I repaired my VS 2015 install but the problem remains. Then I uninstalled and re-installed VS 2015, but the problem is the same. **The same code works fine in VS 2013**...so what could be different with **VS 2015**?

I might be missing something quite obvious and I would appreciate any insights someone can offer.

Comment: Can you please attach your code? so we can help you much better

Comment: Please don't attach _your_ code. Please do compose a good [mcve] that reliably reproduces the problem, and edit your post to include _that_ code. I would start debugging by creating the simplest possible example that still uses `BackgroundWorker` and seeing if the problem still happens. It's my guess that it won't, not in a bare-bones code example. Then you can start trimming your existing problematic code (make a copy of the real code, of course), and see what the last thing you removed is before it starts working correctly.

Comment: @PeterDuniho The code is included now.

Comment: sorry for my comment i don't intend for you to attach your whole code but only the code that shows the problem. i apologize for that

Comment: everything works fine with me, i just copy paste your code & put breakpoints and still it going smooth in me

Comment: Try to run your Visual Studio as Administrator.

Comment: sorry for the edit @Bartlomiej but what you edited were the uniqueness of other programmer.

Comment: @E.Solicito I put it all in to eliminate any doubt. I'm sad (for myself) to hear it works for you. So, it must be something strange about my system...and I really don't want to reinstall my OS. :-(

Comment: sorry for that @John. all i want was to help you

Comment: @RredCat I tried running as admin, symptoms remain the same. I also uninstalled and reinstalled VS 2015, symptoms remain the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was a **bug in VS 2015 which has been fixed in Update 1**.

After updating to VS2015.1 it works fine (can step through the backgroundworker_dowork).

According to the [Help Center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), this is on-topic but since it's a fixed bug perhaps this whole question should be deleted. I will leave that in the hands of the community.